# Titanium - save remote image to filesystem

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm building an app with titanium and I would like to save in the phone, the user's profile picture. In my login function, after the API response, I tried to do :

```
Ti.App.Properties.setString("user_picture_name", res.profil_picture);
var image_to_save = Ti.UI.createImageView({image:img_url}).toImage();
var picture = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, res.profil_picture); //As name, the same as the one in DB
picture.write(image_to_save);
```

And in the view in which I want to display the image :

```
var f = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory,Ti.App.Properties.getString("user_picture_name") );

var image = Ti.UI.createImageView({
    image:f.read(),
    width:200,
    height:100,
    top:20
});
main_container.add(image);
```

But the image doesn't appears. Could someone help me ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 issues with your code:

1 - You cannot use **toImage()** method unless your image view is rendered on UI stack or simply on display. Rather you should use **toBlob()** method.

2 - Point no. 1 will also not work the way you are using because you cannot directly use **toBlob()** method until or unless the image from the url is completely loaded, means until it's shown on image view. To check when the image is loaded, use **[Ti.UI.ImageView onload event](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ImageView-event-load)**

But, there's another better approach to do such type of tasks.

Since you have the image url from your Login API response, you can use this url to fetch image from http client call like this:

```
function fetchImage() {
    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onerror : function() {
            alert('Error fetching profile image');
        },

        onload : function() {
            // this.responseData holds the binary data fetched from url
            var image_to_save = this.responseData;

            //As name, the same as the one in DB
            var picture = Ti.Filesystem.getFile(Ti.Filesystem.applicationDataDirectory, res.profil_picture);
            picture.write(image_to_save);

            Ti.App.Properties.setString("user_picture_name", res.profil_picture);

            image_to_save = null;
        }
    });

    xhr.open("GET", img_url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: you should mark the answer as correct, to credit Prashant and help other users finding a working solution in the future. :)

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to manually cache remote images, because

> Remote images are cached automatically on the iOS platform and, since
>   Release 3.1.0, on the Android platform.

[[see docs here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Image_Best_Practices-section-30082525_ImageBestPractices-Cachingremoteimages) & [credit to Fokke Zandbergen](http://www.tidev.io/2013/12/22/caching-remote-images/)]

Just use the remote image url in your UI, at first access Titanium will download and cache it for you; next accesses to the same image url will actually be on the automatically cached version on local device (no code is best code)

Hth.

Comment: This solution works only for fix urls. If image url changes then it won't work.

Comment: well, I guessed it was worth the mention. thanks for the downvote

Comment: Yes, it was good to mention, but it was not in context to this question and we should always try to put actual answers directly pointing to questions instead of mentioning something else which user has not asked. Since he has mentioned that he wants to save picture in the storage, which also means that he is going to use this image further like updating cropping, resizing, etc. Sorry for down-vote. :)

Comment: no problem at all Prashant, it's fine, and thanks for the time you took to explain it. I see your point, it seems I missed the meaning of his question. 
Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I dont want to modify this picture, but just show it when the user is offline. I didn't know this cache, and I also tried your solution. But when I'm offline, the picture is not here... so, is it a normal thing ?

Comment: Hi, you're welcome.
l, and  it is not what you want to you code to do.
When you receive the img_url from your api

Comment: (sorry for the upper mess, not so used to time limited editing, ouch)

Sure it is not what you want your code to do.
I guess when you receive the img_url from your api then you store it locally before using it again while offline, am I right?

Comment: @PatrickDeMarta, the point in caching is that it works only when you're online. **OR** When your device is online, then it fetch images from local cache memory, but when device is offline - it doesn't fetch from local cache. That's why users need to save those images which should be shown offline in some other accessible directories like appData directory or external storage.